# Giving Ma'aser Money

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

If one has *ma'aser* money, should he give it to poor people, his shul or use it to support Torah institutions?

Are there any halachos of where one should give his *ma'aser* money?

Comment: I thought we had this question already....

Comment: Is there any reason to ask about ma'aser, and not about the optimal recipients of charity in general?

Answer (score 1):

It talks about it in חכמת אדם
 ‏(כלל קמה)‏
 which is based off the ‎(‏ שולחן ערוך רנ"א,  רנ"ב רפ"ב)

you could see  [חכמת אדם](http://hebrewbooks.org/33594)  page 425

I'll just write some of the things I  see there, although I might not be reading them correctly.

Family first, woman before man, clothes before food, sick before healthy marry off orphan/widow before other poor people, talmud chacham before non talmud chacham, people learning before the baismedresh itself.

But basically I think its quite obvious that you should give to hungry, suffering people before kollels and yeshivas.

Not that you shouldnt support them also.

Comment: sorry its annoyingly hard to make the hebrew words right

Comment: thanks for fixing it there was one more in the shulchan aruch, raish pei bais

Comment: this edit is faithful to the original?  @Yehuda